# On Premise to Office 365 guidence needed

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, exchange-2013, microsoft-office-365

I need some here.

I have an Exchange 2010 and 2013 coexistence scenario.  Majority of mailboxes are still Exchange 2010.

I now have licencing and want to move our entire environment into Office365.  I want to start with one email domain, test it for a month then move another domain over.  For example we have @volunteer.domain.com email domain users.  I want to move them over to office365 first and basically use them as guniee pigs, before I move our staff/employee accounts over which are @domain.com.  All of my @volunteer accounts are still on exchange 2010, and all proxy through the exchange 2013 cas servers.  Basically only about 20 accounts have been migrated to exchange 2013.

I feel like I just need some help and direction on which way to go here.

1. Do I first finish the on-premise migration so that everyone is an
   exchange 2013 mailbox, AND THEN setup hybrid with office365 and move
   the mailboxes to the cloud?
2. Do I leave the @volunteer mailboxes in exchange 2010 and setup
   hybrid config, using 2010 or 2013?
3. Do I move the 20 exchange 2013 mailbox users back to 2010 and get
   rid of the on premise 2013 exchange, then setup hybrid and begin
   moving people to office365?

I feel stuck not knowing which way to go forward.

Comment: Do you still need assistance with that?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to gently suggest that you go read https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh852414.aspx. To briefly answer: you can keep your Exchange 2010 and Exchange 2013 servers as they are, set up hybrid coexistence between your existing org and O365, and move mailboxes at your convenience.